# How to pre-process values from spring configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration-files

I have a configuration parameter "myconfig.defaultSize" whose value is defined, for example, as "10MB", in the application.properties file.

In the other hand, I have a @Component class with @ConfigurationProperties annotation mapping those configuration parameter, as follows.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myconfig")
public class StorageServiceProperties {
   private Long defaultSize;
   //...getters and setters
}
```

So, how can I would apply a method to convert the String value into Long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have such generic converter applied on a property-to-property basis. You could register a converter from String to Long but it would be called for every such case (any property of type Long basically).

The purpose of `@ConfigurationProperties` is to map the `Environment` to a higher-level data structure. Perhaps you could do that there?

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myconfig")
public class StorageServiceProperties {
    private String defaultSize;
    // getters and setters

    public Long determineDefaultSizeInBytes() {
        // parsing logic
    }

}
```

If you look at the multipart support in Spring Boot, we [keep the String value and we use the `@ConfigurationProperties` object](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.java) to create a `MultipartConfigElement` that is responsible of the parsing. That way you can specify those special values in code and configuration.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void setDefaultSize(String defaultSize) {
  try {
    this.defaultSize = Long.valueOf(defaultSize);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // handle the exception however you like
  }
}
```